# Why is the button in the parent page view controller not being fired?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a page view controller, and I have a button in the parent view controller and I want to print "called" in the console when it is clicked, but nothing prints. What is wrong? I checked the connection between the button and the code, and it is indeed there. I am not sure if this will affect it, but there is a pan gesture as well.

```
@IBAction func btnclicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("called") //Not printed
}
```

Comment: Have you make touch up inside action connection with button in storyboard?

Comment: Yes the default is touch up inside, and I did not change that. I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: this btncliked event is in page view controller or parent view controller?

Comment: Its in the parent view controller which is then placed inside the page view controller

Comment: Maybe your class is not in memory yet. I mean the parent VC, Please check the navigation hierarchy.

Comment: I know for a fact that it is in memory I have a label at the bottom which indicates which page I am on, and changes as I swipe

Comment: did you implement the page viewcontroller protocol in your root controller?

Comment: @Jobs yes everything is implemented correctly. I have a working pageview controller which displays information, and I am able to swipe through everything. It's just the button which is not firing.

Comment: When I hold on the button, it does not even get highlighted.

Comment: there must be some issue in the way that you've linked everything up. Did you implement a cocoa class for the view in which the button is in?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your class is set on your storyboard scene.
[picture reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qREnv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Swift class for the actions to take place.

Create a new .swift class and create a function in it as:

```
func buttonClicked(button: UIButton)  {

     print("Called")

    }
```

Comment: For the print function to work check that the function buttonClicked is linked to the button as expected. This function prints a message to the standard output, which in this case is the Xcode debug console.

Answer (score 0):

See that your data flow is correct. You should have a root controller for your pageViewController. In it you have to implement your protocols and you can even keep a reference to all the storyboard ids of the viewcontrollers you want to display. Add this code onto this root controller and connect it with the page view controller.

```
if let xyz = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pageView") {

            self.addChildViewController(xyz)
            self.view.addSubview(xyz.view)
            turn = xyz as! UIPageViewController
            turn.dataSource = self
            turn.delegate = self

            turn.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(0)!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            turn.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

p.s. this should be in your viewDidLoad function

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to add your `parent view controllers` view as `child of page view controller`. Also you have to set  `[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];`

I am not much aware about swift so here is the Objective-C code.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```